# Unable to install MS Office, wine1.7, and getting updates

Tags: updates, software-installation, microsoft-office

I am a new ubuntu user, just installed 12.04 LTS. Learned a lot from ubuntu users suggestions on the webs. I am a student and frequent user of MS office. 
However, I am unable to install MS Office as failing to get updates plus installing wine1.7.

`sudo apt-get update` shows something about unable to connect `archive.ubuntu.com` and some files failed to download, they have been ignored or older ones have been used instead.
`sudo apt-get install wine1.7` shows something about unmet dependencies and broken 
packages.

Comment: You are stating to have multiple problems - it's hard to give a solution unless you show us the output of running the commands `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. [Edit] your question after running those commands.

Comment: You could give https://www.libreoffice.org/ a try if ms office is not running stable via wine

Comment: for an in-depth feature comparison see : https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Feature_Comparison:_LibreOffice_-_Microsoft_Office

Comment: yes i a for a time being but when my  class fellows receive my files and open in ms office, the formatting is very much changed.

Comment: @spirit: Paste the output of running the command to http://paste.ubuntu.com and provide us the link to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my 64 bit system OS (ubuntu 12.04) was not updating completely because of the server. I went to the ubuntu software center>edit>software sources>download from> choose the best server> and I accepted the choice by ubuntu. That's it. Changing the mirror actually solved the problem. The sudo apt-get update happened successfully and I then followed the instructions available in forums to install wine and ms office 2007. The rest is good.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Office 2007 on Ubuntu 13.04, and it runs great. Maybe you can use [this link](http://nithinaneeshsct06bt.blogspot.mx/2012/05/install-microsoft-office-2007-in-ubuntu.htm).

First you have to install the libraries that the link tells you to install and then install Office. Office updates have to be installed manually.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

wine 1.7 is not a stable release. remove it and replace it with current stable release 1.6 and then try. also as far as I know, you can install MS Office 2007 but not later versions. for more info, check these links:

- [Install-Microsoft-Office-2007-on-Linux](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Microsoft-Office-2007-on-Linux)
- [Install Microsoft Office 2007 in Ubuntu](http://nithinaneeshsct06bt.blogspot.in/2012/05/install-microsoft-office-2007-in-ubuntu.html)

Comment: when I give the command sudo apt-get install wine1.4 winetricks wine-gecko1.4 following appears:Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package wine-gecko1.4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'wine-gecko1.4' has no installation candidate